# Error compiling metismex in matlab r2013

Tags: c, matlab, visual-c++, mex, metis

I have downloaded and succesfully compiled [metis 5.0.2](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/download) in a win7 x64 pc
and trying to compile [metismex](https://github.com/dgleich/metismex).
I compiled metis with Visual Studio 11 (2012) and using the same compiler from within matlab.
After a lot of experimentation with a ton of errors (mainly owed to paths issues from within the libraries) I have reached a point where I dont know how to proceed, since my knowledge on c and c++ is pretty basic.
So, here's the error :

```
../GKlib/mat_libs/.\stddef.h(16) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow '_SIZE_TYPE__' 
../GKlib/mat_libs/.\stddef.h(19) : error C2085: '_WCHAR_TYPE__' : not in formal parameter list
```

I found out about the inline functions etc, but since the error is within a library and dont exactly know what I should be doing, here I am. So, the error code is produced here :

```
 typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t; 
#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef __WCHAR_TYPE__ wchar_t; 
#endif
```

any suggestions on what I should do without messing it up?
(in case I comment out wchar type, I also have the same error on prtdiff_type)
Thanks in advance

P.S: In case it is needed, here's the whole sttdef.h

```
/* Copyright 2012 The MathWorks, Inc. */

#ifndef _STDDEF_H
#define _STDDEF_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#  define NULL (0)
#else
#  define NULL ((void *)0)
#endif

typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t; 

#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef __WCHAR_TYPE__ wchar_t; 
#endif

typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;

#if (! defined(__cplusplus)) || (! defined(PST_GNU))
# define offsetof(type, field) ((size_t) &((type *)0)->field)
#else
# define offsetof(type, field)                            \
  (__offsetof__(reinterpret_cast<size_t>                  \
        (&reinterpret_cast<const volatile char &> \
         (static_cast<type *>(0)->field))))
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif

#endif /* _STDDEF_H *
```

/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a walk-through of what I did. I'm running R2014a with VS2013 on Win8.1 x64.

#### 1) First we compile metis:

- Download and extract [`metis-5.1.0`](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/fetch/sw/metis/metis-5.1.0.tar.gz) to some location, say `C:\metis-5.1.0`
- Edit `C:\metis-5.1.0\include\metis.h` and set `#define IDXTYPEWIDTH 64` (for x64 architecture)
- Next we generate Visual Studio projects using CMake:

  ```
  > cd C:\metis-5.1.0
  > vsgen -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"
  ```
- Before we build the solution, we need to fix a few things first. Some header files are unnecessarily redefining `rint` function for MSVC (`metisbin.h`, `metislib.h`, and `gk_arch.h`). Remove such lines:

  ```
  #ifdef __MSC__ /* MSC does not have rint() function */
  #define rint(x) ((int)((x)+0.5))  

  /* MSC does not have INFINITY defined */
  #ifndef INFINITY
  #define INFINITY FLT_MAX
  #endif
  #endif
  ```
- Also in `GKlib\gk_externs.h` replace all occurrences of `__thread` with `__declspec(thread)`
- Next open the solution file `C:\metis-5.1.0\build\windows\METIS.sln` in Visual Stduio, and build `ALL_BUILD` target (make sure "x64" in "Release" mode is selected).
- We are mainly interested in the `metis` project. Its result should be stored in `C:\metis-5.1.0\build\windows\libmetis\Release\metis.lib` (a static library).

#### 2) Next we build the MEX-function:

- Download [`metismex`](https://github.com/dgleich/metismex/archive/master.zip) and extract it to a folder inside the previous location (`C:\metis-5.1.0\metismex-master`)
- Again we need to fix a few things: first rename `metismex.c` to `metismex.cpp` (the C++ compiler is much better than the C compiler in Visual Studio!). Next edit this file and replace: `#include <strings.h>` with `#include <string.h>`, and add the following code immediately after it:

  ```
  #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    #define snprintf _snprintf
    #define vsnprintf _vsnprintf
    #define strcasecmp _stricmp
    #define strncasecmp _strnicmp
  #endif
  ```
- Finally start MATLAB, and run the following command to compile the MEX-file:

  ```
  >> cd('C:\metis-5.1.0\metismex-master')
  >> mex -O -largeArrayDims -DWIN32 -DMSC -DUSE_GKREGEX -I../GKlib -I../include -I../libmetis metismex.cpp ../build/windows/libmetis/Release/metis.lib
  ```
- You should now have the final `metismex.mexw64`

I should say that I know nothing about the library, so I cannot guarantee it gives correct results after all the above modifications. I'm just showing how to get it to compile. The code was written with Linux/OSX in mind, and relies on many POSIX features not intended for Windows. Also the whole 32 vs. 64 bit is a bit messy...

Comment: Whoops !! My bad my bad!! Sorry, I should have told that I have downloaded a patched version of metis from here https://github.com/helixhorned/metis/tree/pk (it addressed the isues of gpmentis and ndmetis crashing on win7 machines and it worked for me). Here is the link to the forum that explains : http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/node/1095

Comment: OK problems solved, everything works as you said :D (The errors where owed to the fact that in cmake I hadnt chosen the x64 compiler.) (silly me..) A million thanks :D :D :D :D

Comment: just so you should know, I am posting your solution to David Gleich's github page -with the appropriate reference of course :D